# Chaining `and` function to `selectAll` in spec file throws an error

Tags: angular, chaining, akita

I'm trying to follow official `Akita` docs on unit testing with `Angular`: https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/angular/tests/.

However I'm having problems with mocking `TodosQuery` return value. This is the specific line:

```
todosQuery.selectAll.and.returnValue(of([createTodo(), createTodo()]))
```

And this is the error thrown:

```
Property 'and' does not exist on type '{ (options: SelectAllOptionsA<Todo>): Observable<HashMap<Todo>>; (options: SelectAllOptionsB<Todo>): Observable<...>; (options: SelectAllOptionsC<...>): Observable<...>; (options: SelectAllOptionsD<...>): Observable<...>; (options: SelectAllOptionsE<...>): Observable<...>; (): Observable<...>; }'.
```

Maybe the docs are outdated and this is no longer supported? Is this still the preferred way to mock `Query` returning value?

These are my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@datorama/akita": "^6.2.3",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-entity-service": "^6.2.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-router-store": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ngdevtools": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a missing step in the tests beforeEach

```
spyOn(todosQuery, 'selectAll');
```

Comment: Didn't try it in `beforeEach` but in the end made it work by chaining directly to `spyOn` function call like this:
`spyOn(todosQuery, 'selectAll').and.returnValue(of([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]))`
Thanks for the help

Comment: you can't respy the function that is already spied on. so I would still create spy in the beforeEach hook instead of the test itself